# save a data frame with a list column to tsv

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, dplyr, tibble

I want to save a data frame with a list column to tsv

```
> group_file
# A tibble: 2,233 x 2
   gene_name marker     
   <chr>     <list>     
 1 A3GALT2   <chr [81]> 
 2 AADACL3   <chr [91]> 
 3 AADACL4   <chr [132]>
 4 ABCA4     <chr [756]>
 5 ABCB10    <chr [219]>
 6 ABCD3     <chr [260]>
 7 ABL2      <chr [676]>
 8 ACADM     <chr [305]>
 9 ACAP3     <chr [121]>
10 ACBD3     <chr [200]>
# … with 2,223 more rows
```

and I want to save this to a format like and each row consist of gene name followed by the markers belonging to that gene:

```
GENE1   chrX:4_A/C  chrX:9_A/C  chrX:10_A/C chrX:11_A/C
GENE2   chrX:12_A/C chrX:14_A/C chrX:15_A/C chrX:17_A/C
```

But I couldn't save it directly:

```
> write_tsv(group_file,"../data/group_fie.tsv")
Error: Flat files can't store the list column `marker`
```

What should I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write list columns to csv/tsv. Assuming your data is something like this :

```
df <- structure(list(gene_name = 1:5, marker = list(c("a", "b"), c("b", 
"c", "d"), c("a", "b"), c("a", "b"), c("a", "b"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#    gene_name marker   
#      <int> <list>   
#1         1 <chr [2]>
#2         2 <chr [3]>
#3         3 <chr [2]>
#4         4 <chr [2]>
#5         5 <chr [2]>
```

Here are couple of options that you can consider.

Create new columns for each marker :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  unnest(marker) %>%
  group_by(gene_name) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('col', row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = marker) %>%
  ungroup -> df1

df1
#  gene_name col1  col2  col3 
#      <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1         1 a     b     NA   
#2         2 b     c     d    
#3         3 a     b     NA   
#4         4 a     b     NA   
#5         5 a     b     NA
```

Create one comma separated string combining all markers for each gene.

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(marker = map_chr(marker, toString))
df2

#  gene_name marker 
#      <int> <chr>  
#1         1 a, b   
#2         2 b, c, d
#3         3 a, b   
#4         4 a, b   
#5         5 a, b
```

You should now be able to write both `df1` and `df2` to csv/tsv file.

Comment: Ronak, in your second approach can we do its reverse.  I mean if we have a column where multiple values are stored comma separated, then can it be converted to list_col?

Comment: Yes, you can split the data into list columns. `df2$b <- strsplit(df2$marker, ',\\s*')`

Comment: Ronak, I just read this--can this same list-->string-->list procedure be done even on numeric data? When I try it, all my numeric data have been converted to characters and I can't seem to get them back to numeric.